# Where Can I download CentOS x86_64 DVD .iso Valid File?

Tags: iso, centos6.5, broken-image

I have download CentOS 6.5 .iso from kernel.org, but download complete before reaching its actual size, Googled for iso file and I got same file everywhere, every mirror has the same file.

and I am sorry for violating stack overflow rules and regulation but I need it desperately and I want you guys to delete my question as soon as I got my answer.
thank you stack overflow !

Comment: What makes you think the image is broken? First, have you tried to [verify](https://wiki.centos.org/Download/Verify#head-6466f3e82b54592f00381115a41c87348007216a)  it?

Comment: Yeah, 547 files are broken during extraction via universal usb installer

Comment: I mean when file size is a 4 GB then how can its complete upon 2.7 GB?

Comment: Because the last 1.3 GB might well be null. Many protocols support compression and can exploit that. Anyway [here](http://vault.centos.org/6.5/isos/x86_64/).

Comment: Thank You ! Elliot

Comment: But it has mirror redirect to http://vault.centos.org/notonvault.html